# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize does not work on a external Xib cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I have been struggling for 2 days with this problem.

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView on the storyboard.

But I want to reuse the design for a custom cell so I use an Xib file to design the cell.

The cells contains a label that gets the content at runtime so the height of it varies.

I am using autolayout I have all the constraints and set lines of my label as 0;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  self.tableView.dataSource = self;
  self.tableView.delegate = self;

  [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PostingTableViewCell" bundle:   [NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PostingCell"];

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostingCell";

self.customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (self.customCell == nil)
{
    self.customCell = [[PostingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSString *contentString = [post objectForKey:@"content"];

self.customCell.contentLabel.text = contentString;

self.customCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.customCell.bounds));


[self.customCell setNeedsLayout];
[self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];

CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

return height;

}
```

My code works when I put my custom cell on my tableViewController in the storyboard, but when I migrate it to the xib file, the height of the tableviewcell no longer adjusts.

here is a screen shot of my xib file and constraints
 [image]

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostingCell";

PostingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSString *contentString = [post objectForKey:@"content"];

cell.contentLabel.text = contentString;
}
```

Simulator Screenshot
[image]

When I hard code the height to 150 screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Have you added constraints to the custom cell?

Comment: I have all the constraints

Comment: Just curious, Why are you setting up your cell in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method? Also, please post a screenshot of what it looks like.

Comment: What does it look like in the simulator? I'm trying to figure out what your'e trying to accomplish

Comment: I'll screenshot the simulator right now

Comment: simulator screenshot posted: The cells height ended up being the same. In the first cell the text should be multiple lines and the height should be expanded. Instead it truncated at one line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64912/discussion-between-newengland-and-user3081516).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why you're doing any of this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostingCell";

self.customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (self.customCell == nil)
{
self.customCell = [[PostingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Try this
1. Adjust the height of the cell in xib. 
2. Try something like this

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
return self.customCell.bounds.size.height;
}
```

Comment: I mean it still gives the same height for all cells

Comment: Try hard coding `return 150.0`

Comment: I'll post the screen shot for you

Comment: I still cannot come up with a solution :(((